# Division of Line Segments (Locating a Point)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A line passes through A(2,3) and B(5,7).
Find:
(a) The coordinates of the point P on AB 
extended through B to P so that P is twice 
as far from A as from B;
(b) the coordinates if P is on AB extended
through A so that P is twice as far from B
as from A.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Please include everything you have tried so far.

Comment: I got 2 terminal points which has coordinates (a)P(8,11) and (b)P(0.5,1).

Comment: as I graph it. It doesnt seem like it concide with the given problems. I use an equation x=x1+r(x2-x1)

Answer (score 0):

Equation of your line is $y=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{3}x$, which you can derive by solving $3=a+2b$ and $7=a+5b$. A point on the line twice as far from A than from B will have $x=5+(5-2)$. A point on the line twice as far from B than from A will have $x=2-(5-2)$.

Comment: Pardon me good sir. I am quite confuse about the equation line.

Comment: A line passing through your $A$ and $B$ points is a collection of points $(y,x)$, where $y=1/3+4/3\cdot x$.